# bootstrap dualistbox how get values selected

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using this plugin for bootstrap 3 https://github.com/Geodan/DualListBox, and this example https://jsfiddle.net/hh2zrt82/ 
 I am trying to get a selected values but I can't, How can I to get a selected values.? 
Apreciate your help.

```
 var data = [
        {
            "id": 56,
            "countryList_id": 10,
            "port_iso": "India-pok"
        },
        {
            "id": 57,
            "countryList_id": 10,
            "port_iso": "India-nmp"
        },
        {
            "id": 58,
            "countryList_id": 10,
            "port_iso": "India-cop"
        },
        {
            "id": 61,
            "countryList_id": 2,
            "port_iso": "Bangladesh-dhp"
        },
        {
            "id": 62,
            "countryList_id": 2,
            "port_iso": "Bangladesh-brp"
        },
        {
            "id": 63,
            "countryList_id": 3,
            "port_iso": "Singapore-pos"
        },
        {
            "id": 64,
            "countryList_id": 3,
            "port_iso": "Singapore-SIN"
        },
        {
            "id": 65,
            "countryList_id": 3,
            "port_iso": "Singapore-zxczx"
        },
        {
            "id": 66,
            "countryList_id": 2,
            "port_iso": "Bangladesh-qewrqwe"
        },
        {
            "id": 67,
            "countryList_id": 3,
            "port_iso": "Singapore-erer"
        },
        {
            "id": 68,
            "countryList_id": 3,
            "port_iso": "Singapore-SIN"
        }
    ];
    var port_ids = [65,66,67];
    var options = '';

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var a = 1;
                    for (var j = 0; j < port_ids.length; j++) {
                        // Appending "selected" attribute to the values which are already selected
                        if (port_ids[j] == data[i]["id"]) {
                            options += '<option value="' + data[i]["id"] + '" selected="selected">' + data[i]["port_iso"] + '</option>';
                            a = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    if (a == 1) {
                        options += '<option value="' + data[i]["id"] + '">' + data[i]["port_iso"] + '</option>';
                    }
                }


                $("select#country-of-operation-edit").empty().append(options);

               $("#country-of-operation-edit").DualListBox();
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could do something like this:

`$('option[selected="selected"]')`

You might want to add a class to you options in which case you would do:

`$('option.className[selected="selected"]')`

This will get you an array of all selected options.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get selected values, before you have to set name attribute:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country-of-operation-edit[]"  multiple="multiple" data-json="false" id="country-of-operation-edit">
```

after you can get the values so:

```
$('[name="country-of-operation-edit[]"]').val()
```